# Kafka POM Dependency Issue - ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.kafka.test.TestCondition

Tags: java, maven, kotlin, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm seeing - `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kafka/test/TestCondition` in my integration tests. I think this is something related to way the repository import the `kafka` related packages. I'm adding pom dependencies with `scope` and `classifiers` used.

Could you please help fixing this?

```
     <kafka-clients.version>0.10.2.1</kafka-clients.version>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-clients.version}</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-clients.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-clients.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>${kafka-clients.version}</version>
        <classifier>test</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

TestCondition is in kafka-clients-version-test.jar
So add classifer test to  'kafka-clients' artifactId

Comment: That is resolved but now I see another exception. Seems unrelated though - org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Could not instantiate class www.avro.support.AvroSerde Does it have a public no-argument constructor?

Comment: @Prakhar www.avro.support.AvroSerde isn't  Apache Kafka Class. I need more 
 code and stacktrace